# Conditional statement using rexep with bash

Tags: regex, bash

I want to use the "conditional regexp" structure from bash, present since the third version of bash (circa 2004).
It's supposed to go like this:

```
if [[ $string =~ $regexp ]]; then
#do smthg
else
#do somthg else
fi
```

So here's my code, following this structure, and its role is to check if the name contained in SSID is presend in the output from *iw dev wlan0 link* :

```
if [[ $(iw dev wlan0 link) =~ $SSID+ ]]; then 
    #do sthming 
else
    echo "wrong network"

fi
```

For some reason that i can't decipher, this statement works pretty well if I run it right into the bash shell, like

```
if [[ $(iw dev wlan0 link) =~ $SSID+ ]]; then echo found; else echo not found; fi
```

But if i run it inside the script its contained, it'll spit out:

```
scripts/ssidchecker.sh: 22: [[: not found
```

22 being the line of the "fi" keyword. **The strangest thing is that it will always execute the code contained in the "else" statement**

Is "not found" meant to indicate me that the regexp dind't find anything in that string? Is it a real error message?

Comment: You sure you have a `#!/bin/bash` or some appropriate header in your `.sh` file?

Comment: Thanks for answering :) Yeah I did put `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of my .sh file.

Comment: Does it work when you invoke the script using `bash scripts/ssidchecker.sh`?

Comment: It might help to turn on shell debug/trace `set -vx`. Then you can see what values are being used with your `$SSID+`. Personally, I'm skeptical that that variable and the following '+' are working the way that you want them to work. Consider editing your post with the minimal amount from debug/trace output. Good luck

Comment: Invoking bash instead of sh to execute the script did the trick, thanks bmk ;)

Comment: `sh` refers to the historic Bourne Shell and many (differing) re-implementations of it, although it has later been standardized by POSIX. Bash is the "Bourne Again Shell", which is way more complex with a huge feature-set. When you specify `#!/bin/sh` you should conform to the language specified by POSIX (or the even more primitive historic one, if you want absolute compatibility). If you want to use bash features, use `#!/bin/bash`, and use *.bash if you'll use a file-name extension (no extension is fine too for executable scripts).

Comment: Maybe someone could create an answer out of all these good comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting Note: Answer created with input from comments in question, especially in response of the last comment.

First, what is `[[`? It is a shell keyword.

```
samveen@maverick:~$ type [[
[[ is a shell keyword
```

This means that `[[` is an internal keyword of bash, not a command and thus will not work with other shells. Thus, your error output

```
scripts/ssidchecker.sh: 22: [[: not found
```

means that the shell you're using is probably

- Not bash
- A version of bash older than 2.02 (`[[` introduced in Bash-2.02)

Given that 2.02 is a really really old version (pre Y2K), all this just points to the fact that the shell you're using to run the script is probably not `/bin/bash`, instead probably being `/bin/sh` which is the most common path used for Bourne shell scripts `shebang` (the `#!`) line.

Please change that to `/bin/bash` or explicitly run `bash scripts/ssidchecker.sh` and you're good to go.

As to why the `else` section was always executed, the `[[` command not being found is the same as a failure (non-zero return value), from the viewpoint of `if`. Thus the `else` section is executed.

```
samveen@maverick:~$ /bin/whosyourdaddy
-bash: /bin/whosyourdaddy: No such file or directory
samveen@maverick:~$ echo $?
127
```

As a side note on portability, the bash hackers wiki also says the following about the `[[` keyword:

> Amongst the major "POSIX-shell superset languages" (for lack of a
>   better term) which do have `[[`, the test expression compound command is
>   one of the very most portable non-POSIX features. **Aside from the =~
>   operator**, almost every major feature is consistent between Ksh88,
>   Ksh93, mksh, Zsh, and Bash. Ksh93 also adds a large number of unique
>   pattern matching features not supported by other shells including
>   support for several different regex dialects, which are invoked using
>   a different syntax from Bash's `=~`, though `=~` is still supported by ksh
>   and defaults to ERE.

Thus your script will probably fail on the `=~` even if the shell supports `[[`, in case the shell isn't `bash` but supports `[[`.

Comment: Whoa, that truly was a rich answer. All my thanks to you sir! (And you were right, that was the true problem, although i solved it some time ago... still, thanks a lot!).